# Use a substitution to turn $\cos(y)y'+ \tan(x)\sin(y)=\sin(x)$ into a linear differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

$$\cos(y)\frac{dy}{dx} + \tan(x)\sin(y)=\sin(x)$$
Is there any method to find a substitution to fit this purpose? Or is it purely done through brute force/trial and error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation this way..

$$\cos(y)\frac{dy}{dx} + \tan(x)\sin(y)=\sin(x)$$
$$ \implies (\sin(y))' + \tan(x)\sin(y)=\sin(x)$$
And the equation becomes linear of first order
$$ \implies z' + \tan(x)z=\sin(x)$$
Where $z=\sin y$

Comment: Not so much a hint as a full answer.

Comment: @robjohn I didn't want to solve it ...just show him a substitution..But you 're completely right this isnt not a hint I  will change it

Comment: His question regarded the substitution phase only.

Comment: Yes true @RhysHughes  I didnt pay attention I corrected it..

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\int{\cos(y)\frac{dy}{dx}dx}=\int{\cos(y)dy}=\sin y$$